# Update based on Timestamp in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a Firebase DB as follows:

```
{
  "page_id": {
    "user_1": {
      "messages": {
        "1502774604": {
          "timestamp": 1502774604,
          "user": false,
          "content": "Hi"
        },
        "1502774613": {
          "timestamp": 1502774613,
          "user": false,
          "content": "Hello"
        },
        "1502791814": {
          "timestamp": 1502791814,
          "user": false,
          "content": "How are you"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to set all 'user' field to 'true' where the timestamp is less than '1502791814'. Is it possible in Firebase?

The SQL for the same will be something like

> UPDATE messages SET user = true WHERE timestamp <= 1502791814

PS: I'm using JavaScript client

Answer (score 3):

Please consider doing the following:

```
firebase.database().ref('page_id/user1/messages').orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(1502791814)
   .on('value',function(snap){
    //Now snap is an array of nodes that you wanted
    //Each node can be reached by using the following
    snap.forEach(function(eachSnap){
    //Complete here for update stuff

    });

});
```

Hope that works!

Comment: I left the update part to you. You can use set method or update method. However, update method would be more efficient. Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data

Comment: Ok. will check that. The syntax will be almost same if you use nodejs too right?

Comment: It is slightly different. Look at the admin sdk doc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-ordered-data

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start Check here to grant access to admin priveleges on node.js